# how to use Email Audit API with gdata python client library?

Tags: python, gdata-python-client, google-email-audit-api

When I use gdata-python-client library https://github.com/google/gdata-python-client/blob/master/samples/apps/email_audit_email_monitoring.py, I met an error at the beginning.

```
import re
import sys
import gdata
from gdata.apps.audit.service import AuditService

consumer_key = ""
consumer_secret = ""
domain = "connect-with.in"

service = AuditService(domain=domain, source='emailAuditSample')
service.SetOAuthInputParameters(gdata.auth.OAuthSignatureMethod.HMAC_SHA1, consumer_key, consumer_secret)
request_token = service.FetchOAuthRequestToken()
service.SetOAuthToken(request_token)
auth_url = service.GenerateOAuthAuthorizationURL()
print auth_url
raw_input('Manually go to the above URL and authenticate.'
          'Press Return after authorization.')
service.UpgradeToOAuthAccessToken()
```

It always says that

```
in line 12 gdata.service.FetchingOAuthRequestTokenFailed: {'status': 400, 'body': 'Consumer is not registered: 138497053107-69esj3btdoq14i27qtqkuhr26vfiq65s.apps.googleusercontent.com\n\n', 'reason': 'Non 200 response on fetch request token'}
```

I used client id and client secret applied in Google developer console but it doesn't work. So which key and secret will work?

Comment: Where do you define Auth url params and scope?

Answer (score 0):

Consumer Key and Consumer secret are different from Client Id and Client Secret.

Consumer Key and Consumer secret belong to the Domain. In order to get those values in Admin Console go to "Security > Advanced Settings (click on show more if necesary) > Manage Oauth Domain Key"  and there you can find those values.

Try with those values, let me know if you keep getting errors.